# TextAnnotation on C# Chart is not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, data-visualization

I have an ASP.NET MVC application. This application needs to create a donut chart at runtime and save the image to the file system. The donut chart has to include a text annotation that will be generated and added at runtime. Currently, I can create a donut chart successfully. However, the text annotation never appears. In addition, no error is being thrown. For the life of me, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here is what I'm trying:

```
string[] xValues = { "1", "2" };
double[] yValues = { 30, 70 };

// Create a donut chart
Chart chart = new Chart();
chart.Width = 360;
chart.Height = 240;

// Setup the custom color palette
chart.Palette = ChartColorPalette.None;
chart.PaletteCustomColors = GetPaletteColors();

// Build a donut series
Series series = new Series("Default");
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Doughnut;
chart.Series.Add(series);

// Define the chart area
ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea();
chartArea.Position = new ElementPosition(0, 1.9f, 59.5f, 100);
chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);

// Create the axes as necessary
Axis yAxis = new Axis(chartArea, AxisName.Y);
Axis xAxis = new Axis(chartArea, AxisName.X);

// Bind the data to the chart
chart.Series["Default"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);

// Add the text information
TextAnnotation annotation = new TextAnnotation();
annotation.Text = GetText();
annotation.Font = new Font(new FontFamily("Verdana"), 10.5f);
annotation.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 45, 45, 45);
annotation.X = 10;
annotation.Y = 10;
annotation.BringToFront();
chart.Annotations.Add(annotation);

chart.SaveImage("chart.png", ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

Why isn't the TextAnnotation appearing on the Donut Chart? Thank you so MUCH for any help. I've been beating my head on this for a day now.

Comment: I encountered no problem running your code in ASP.NET MVC 4. Are you sure that GetText() is not NullOrWhiteSpace ?